# Sumif formula for chosen criteria ranging this date of to this date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

hi guys so im having trouble with this sumif. i can make other formulas to work for simple sumifs. but this one is not working. im trying to sum this given criterion

=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$33,$B$4:B$33,$A$4:$A$33,">"&$G$6,$H6,$A$4:$A$33,"<="&I6)

here is the sample sheet im playing with before doing it to the actual sheet.
[image]

this is what i want to happen

ex. if "Line 1" is chosen how many minutes it consume during this dates from 8-july-22 upt to 13-aug-22.

Comment: It needs to be like this, you are using wrong syntax `=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$33,$B$4:$B$33,$G6,$A$4:$A$33,">="&$H6,$A$4:$A$33,"<="&$I6)` --> learn from Microsoft Documentations [SUMIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: that was fast. now i understand that I'm using wrong syntax. it's now working well. thank you so much.

Comment: yes, it is now working well. it gives me the correct answer if the given criteria are chosen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the formula like as given below, `SUMIFS()` syntax was not applied in correct order.

```
=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$33,$B$4:$B$33,$G6,$A$4:$A$33,">="&$H6,$A$4:$A$33,"<="&$I6)
```

Learn how to use **[SUMIFS()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)** Function from Microsoft Documentation.